# Last Name attribute not available for Read/Write in Delegation of Control Wizard

Tags: active-directory, delegation

I am using Active Directory Users and Computers version 6.1.7601.17514

I am attempting to delegate the ability for our HR users to edit the First and Last Name for user accounts in Active Directory.  I am using the Active Directory Delegation of Control Wizard to do this.  My process is like so:

1. Right click the OU
2. Delegate Control
3. add my group
4. create a custom task to delegate
5. Only the following objects in the folder
6. check User Objects
7. uncheck General and check Property-specific

I can find `First Name` (and all the other attributes I want to delegate the control of) but not `Last Name`.  I did some searching and found that some of these attributes may be filtered out.  Apparently if one edits `dssec.dat` found in `%systemroot%\system32` and changes `sn=7` to `sn=0` in the `[user]` section this should allow the Last Name attribute to be viewed in the Delegation of Control Wizard.  I have done this but Last Name still doesn't show up for Read/Write.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed `sn=7` to `sn=0` and now I can see `Last Name` attribute.

*Don't forget to restart ADUC after changes made to `dssec.dat`*